# Use double parameter in filter MDX

Tags: sql-server, mdx

I try to execute mdx in SQL Server, and I have a filter like this:

```
*FILTER([Dim BSC].[BSCID].CHILDREN, [Dim BSC].[BSCID].CURRENTMEMBER  = 
[Dim BSC].[BSCID].&[1] )
```

It works correctly, but now I want to execute [BSCID].&[1] and [BSCID].&[2] at the same time so I change it to

```
*FILTER([Dim BSC].[BSCID].CHILDREN, [Dim BSC].[BSCID].CURRENTMEMBER  = 
[Dim BSC].[BSCID].&[1,2] )
```

But it returns empty result, how can I do double parameter to filter it? Regards

I also try

```
*FILTER([Dim BSC].[BSCID].CHILDREN, [Dim BSC].[BSCID].CURRENTMEMBER  = 
[Dim BSC].[BSCID].&[1].&[2] )
```

but still getting empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why bother using FILTER, you could just use a set with the two members you are interested in:

```
*{ 
       [Dim BSC].[BSCID].&[1],
     [Dim BSC].[BSCID].&[2] 
  }
```